# Help me understand this algorithm problem.

Tags: algorithms, summation

First, I'm not looking for an answer here, I'm just looking to understand the problem so that I can prove it. I'm trying to analyzing the worst case running time of an algorithm, and it must has summation notation. What keeping me back is that I don't understand how to express `doSomething(n-j)` in summation ( I know that `doSomething(k)` takes `c * k` operations for some constant `c > 0` (stated in the problem), so it is not constant in this case). The other two loops have starting points (e.g. `i = 1` or `j = i`).  Anyway, the pseudo-code is stated blow:

```
function(n)
    for int i from 1 to n
        for int j from i to n
           doSomething(n - j)
        endfor
    endfor
endfunction
```

I can express the nested for loop in summation as follow:

$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n doSomething(n-j)$

I think I need one more summation, it's just that I don't know how to express it, maybe something like:

$\sum_{k=?}^{n-j}$

I could be wrong here. 
Could anyone please provide me with some hints in this problem? Thanks a lot.

EDIT: since `doSomething(k)` takes `c * k` operations, can I express it as follow:

$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n c*k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, instead of $doSomething(n-j)$, write $c\cdot (n-j)$  since that is how many operations will be performed. So the total number of operations is

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i}^nc\cdot (n-j)=c\cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i}^n(n-j)\right)$$

Now, first evaluate the inner sum:

$$\sum_{j=i}^n (n - j)$$

This is a sum of all numbers between $0$ and $n-i$, so it is equal to $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-i} k$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you! yes, I can take it from here.

Answer (score 2):

If `doSomething(k)` takes `ck` operations for some constant `c>0`, then it takes `c(n-j)` operations to do `doSomething(n-j)`, where `j` is given by the previous loop.

That is, `doSomething(n-j)` has complexity $O\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-j}c\right)$, since $\sum_{k=1}^{n-j}c =c(n-j).$

Now, the entire algorithm has complexity
$$O\left( \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n \sum_{k=1}^{n-j}c \right).$$

Comment: Thanks! your answer is right and informative but the other person also answered this and he answered before you like 1 min! so I gave him the correct answer.  I'm so sorry, I don't have enough reputation to even give you a thumbs up!

Comment: @Impalerz It's no problem! :) Glad to help!